# Where to Learn Cycles Material Nodes from basics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is there any video tutorial series learning cycles material nodes. Where can i learn material nodes for cycles right from the basics. What are different nodes and in what order i can connect. What effect i get to what node i connect. etc. All the video on Youtube i have seen are base on topic. For example how to give Steel effect or plastic,etc. I did not find a complete series on cycles node material. Any help or suggestion where can i learn. Thanks

Comment: check out Grant Aabbitt's youtube channel. Node school tutorial series, where he goes through explaining how to construct an entire node tree from scratch using principle BSDF. You can also check out blender insight youtube channel for more in-depth videos on cycle's nodes.

Answer (score 4):

Each node is very basic and very descriptive. For example, A Mix node mixes 2 input based on a factor value, a SplitXYZ node splits the input into XYZ. A simple online search should help if you still need clarification.

I think what you need to learn is the high level concept of shading and texturing. Look up "PBR material" basics, That should get you started learning about how the shaders behave, how inputs such as albedo, normal, roughness affects the surface, and how to create steel, plastic, etc.

I also suggest you focus on learning about the principled shader(as oppose to individual shaders such as glossy or diffuse), as it's the most artist friendly, complete, and industry-accepted pbr shading model.

Comment: Thanks but i want to learn each nodes right from the basic how can i connect the nodes in order and what effect i get if i add some nodes. Some time i watch video they just show like professional add this node then color ramp etc. But im confuse when color ram or light weight etc node used and each node have small options. I have search but did not get help or video tutorial how to start from basic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at blender Manual Docs. There you would description of each and every node and you can learn more things there as well.